# Is there a way to compute the standard error for GAM models using effectfun() within spatstat?

Tags: gam, spatstat

I am using spatstat version 3.0.2 to explore settlement patterns in archaeological data in five different periods throughout prehistory. I have formulated several point process models with different covariates including elevation, slope, etc. I started exploring GAM models and I would like to compare models that were not fitted using GAM with GAM models.
I have a question as to the use of effectfun. Is there a way to compute the standard error of models fitted using GAM? The problem that I am facing is that effectfun does not show the standard error for models that were fit using GAM. So, for GAM models effectfun just provides me  with the fitted line.

I have tried to recreate this problem with the bei dataset.

```
data(bei)
data(bei.extra)
elev <-  bei.extra$elev
fitNoGam <- ppm(bei~elev)
fitGam <- ppm(bei~s(elev),use.gam=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(predict(fitNoGam))
plot(predict(fitGam))
plot(effectfun(fitNoGam,"elev",se.fit=T))
plot(effectfun(fitGam,"elev")) #does not allow the calculation of standard errors
```

In the effectfun plots it is clear that I can get the standard error for non GAM models through se.fit=T. Is there a way to compute the standard error for GAM models as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what you mean by "does not allow". It would be better to report the exact error message that you got from the software.

When I run your example code, there is an error message saying that the function `s` was not found. This is a bug. The bug can be traced to `predict.ppm`.

I have now fixed the bug in the development version of `spatstat.model` version `3.2-1.007` which you can download from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat.model).

Comment: Professor Baddeley many thanks for your prompt reply and quick action on the matter. 
The exact  error message I got from the software when I was trying to run plot(effectfun(fitGam,"elev",se.fit=T)) is as follows:
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': could not find function "s"
In addition: Warning message:
model was fitted by gam(); asymptotic variance calculation ignores this

I will now donload the development version of spatstat.model and give this a go. Many thanks!!

Comment: If my answer was satisfactory for you, please 'accept' the answer.